# Segmentation Fault when using printf

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from a file and print every string read. However i get a segmentation fault when i try to print it.

Debugging tells me that my error is because of the line : `printf("%s\n",test);`

My function for retrieving the strings is :

```
char* Lire_string(){
     size_t size = 10 ;
     char *symbole ;
     symbole = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);
     size_t len = 0 ;
     if(!symbole) return symbole ; 
     car_cour = Lire_car(fichier);
     if (car_cour == '"'){
         do {
            symbole[len] = car_cour ;
            car_cour = Lire_car(fichier);
            len++;
            if(len==size){
                symbole = realloc(symbole, sizeof(char)*(size *= 2));
                if(!symbole) return symbole ;
            }
         }while(car_cour != '"' );

         symbole[len] = car_cour ;

         symbole[len++] = '\0' ;

         return realloc(symbole, sizeof(char)*len) ;
     }
}
```

My main is :

```
fichier = fopen("export.json","r");

if ((fichier != NULL)){
    do {
       char* test = Lire_string();
       printf("%s\n",test);
       free(test);
    } while (feof(fichier)==0);
}
else {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
return 0;
```

I tried looking at similar questions but they didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: It's not because the `printf` but because of what you are passing to it. And that can be checked using the debuggger

Comment: If you get a segmentation fault on `printf("%s\n", test)`, you (a) are lucky and (b) have a null pointer, or perhaps a pointer to random address space that isn't mapped anywhere.  These days, `printf()` seems to protect itself from null pointers — I'm not convinced that's a good thing — so your pointer is probably out of control.  Maybe uninitialized.  Or, possibly, you have not null terminated your string so `printf()` is reading data it isn't supposed to.  That's all without looking further than the comment about `printf("%s\n", test)` crashing.

Comment: `Lire_string` seems to have paths that don't return at all.

Comment: In your function, you have `car_cour` which is, apparently, a global variable — I don't see its definition in the function. And `Lire_car` is presumably a 'read character' function, similar to `getc()` et al. Note that if `realloc()` fails, the notation `symbole = realloc(symbole, sizeof(char)*(size *= 2));` guarantees a memory leak — you no longer have a pointer to the previously allocated memory because you zapped it with the null return. You should always save the pointer into a local variable and test that before changing the main pointer (`symbole` being the main pointer in this context).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler actually... GCC optimizes `printf("%s\n", test)` into `puts(test)` which doesn't have NULL protection in glibc ;)

Comment: PeterJ is correct - you're missing the return statement completely in case the first `if` condition is false - then *use* of the return value from a function that explicitly didn't return anything has undefined behaviour.

Comment: Usual case of ignoring warnings - `they are so annoying`

Comment: Put this right after `printf("%s\n",test);` and test again: `if (test == NULL) {printf("test == NULL, investigate why\n"); exit(1);}`

Comment: This is a good example why using one return point is safer & easier to read,.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Yes, I still forget that GCC does those sorts of modifications.

Comment: @PeterJ I don't necessarily agree with that. As long as you don't ignore warnings what's the harm in multiple return points? And in fact I think its easier to read (multiple `return`s or `goto` statements) if your function does a bunch of error checking at the beginning... that saves you from a cascade of indented `if` statements and a lot of horizontal scrolling.

Comment: @yano you do not have to. Everyone writes code as consider the best way.

Comment: @PeterJ ah ok, my apologies,, I interpreted your statement as an accepted rule. I have heard of groups that enforce one `return` statement per function.. never made sense to me. But if that's the consensus of the group, fine by me

Comment: @yano `I have heard of groups` - aviation & motor industry for example.

Comment: @PeterJ one good example there at least :)

Comment: @yano misra  - good enough example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151417/discussion-between-yano-and-peterj).

Answer (score 3):

You probably got some warnings as your function returns something only if `car_cour == '"'`. Otherwise there is no explicit return expression